# Errors in efforts to write code for fullCalendar without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I saw a CodePen that allowed dragging an event from FullCalendar to trash or back to an external list. I forked the CodePen: https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/EMJWQP?editors=1111. The JavaScript part of the working code with jQuery is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {

            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    });

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendarSchedule').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        dragRevertDuration: 0,
        drop: function() {
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                console.log(this);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo( '#external-events-listing' ).text( event.title );
                el.draggable({
                  zIndex: 999,
                  revert: true, 
                  revertDuration: 0 
                });
                el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
            }
        }
    });
    var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {
        var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
        var offset = external_events.offset();
        offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
        offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

        // Compare
        if (x >= offset.left
            && y >= offset.top
            && x <= offset.right
            && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I would like to write the code without using jQuery. So, I tried to change jQuery to vanilla JavaScript. But, the calendar is not even displayed in the screen.

This is how I tried: https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/bZyaQj?editors=1111.

The JavaScript part with vanilla JavaScript I tried is the following:

```
/* initialize the external events
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
var draggable_events = document.querySelectorAll('#external-events .fc-event');

for(var i=0; i<draggable_events.length; i++){
    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    draggable_events[i].fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        title: draggable_events[i].innerText, // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable
    draggable_events[i].draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag     
    });
}

/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendarSchedule');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      editable: true,
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
      dragRevertDuration: 0,
      drop: function() {
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if (document.getElementById('drop-remove').checked = true) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            this.remove();
        }
      },
      eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

        if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
            calendarEl.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
            var el = document.querySelector('fc-event').setAttribute("id", "external-events-listing").text( event.title );
            el.draggable({
              zIndex: 999,
              revert: true, 
              revertDuration: 0 
            });
            el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
        }
      }
    }
});

var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {
    var external_events = document.getElementById('external-events');
    var offset = external_events.offset();
    offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
    offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

    // Compare
    if (x >= offset.left && y >= offset.top && x <= offset.right && y <= offset .bottom){ 
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the CodePen, I don't see any errors. But, when I test with my app I'm working on, I see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: draggable_events[i].fullCalendar is not a function
    at viewMonthly.js:15
```

I'm not even sure how many problems are there in total to solve to make the code work with vanilla JavaScript... :(

So, I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: If you want to change js for learning , it is worth for you . But if for project just use jquery , no loss at all

Comment: @ ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ Yeah, I'm doing it to improve my understanding of vanilla JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fullCalendar in versions prior to V4 is a jquery plugin and needs jquery to work

Comment: Ah...! I just checked the blog post with the title "V4 Officially Released": https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2019/03/v4-officially-released. Yeah... indeed! Thanks for your answer!